# Replace Multiple Special Chars in Multiple Fields SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a C# application that generates an SQL query that should be used to remove special chars from user selected columns in SQL Server. The query I have at the moment is:

```
UPDATE [TableA] 
SET [EpiNum] = REPLACE([EpiNum], SUBSTRING([EpiNum], PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum]), 1), ''), 
    [Name] = REPLACE([Name], SUBSTRING([Name], PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name]), 1), ''), 
    [Acct] = REPLACE([Acct], SUBSTRING([Acct], PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct]), 1), '') 
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum]) <> 0 OR 
      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name]) <> 0 OR 
      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct]) <> 0;
GO
```

This works to remove the first special char but if the string has multiple special charaters, it only removes the first

1. "Salaries & Wages" becomes "Salaries Wages" GOOD!

but

2. "Salaries & Wages - Other" becomes "Salaries Wages - Other" BAD!

My question is:

How can I amend the above query to remove *multiple* special characters whilst *still* being able to execute that query via C#?

Thanks for your time.

---

Edit. Obviously I could do something like

```
declare @input varchar(500), @Action char(1)
set @Input = '80-82/5 O$%*#@)(J^#oh!@!n & '' Bacon St'
set @Action = 'A'

    DECLARE @i int
    DECLARE @result varchar(500)
    SET @result = @input

    if @Action = 'A'
    BEGIN
        SET @i = patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @result)
        WHILE @i > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @result = STUFF(@result, @i, 1, '')
            SET @i = patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @result)
        END
    END

print @Input
print @Result
```

But I cannot see how to adapt such a query to work on multiple fields and from C#. Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) in order to recursively apply `REPLACE` function:

```sql
;WITH StripSpecialChars AS (
   SELECT id, 0 AS lvl,
          [EpiNum] = REPLACE([EpiNum], SUBSTRING([EpiNum], x.i, 1), ''), 
          [Name] = REPLACE([Name], SUBSTRING([Name], y.i, 1), ''), 
          [Acct] = REPLACE([Acct], SUBSTRING([Acct], z.i, 1), '')   
   FROM TableA
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum])) AS x(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name])) AS y(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct])) AS z(i)
   WHERE x.i <> 0 OR y.i <> 0 OR z.i <> 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT id, lvl = lvl + 1,                       
          [EpiNum] = REPLACE([EpiNum], SUBSTRING([EpiNum], x.i, 1), ''), 
          [Name] = REPLACE([Name], SUBSTRING([Name], y.i, 1), ''), 
          [Acct] = REPLACE([Acct], SUBSTRING([Acct], z.i, 1), '') 
   FROM StripSpecialChars 
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum])) AS x(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name])) AS y(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct])) AS z(i)
   WHERE x.i <> 0 OR y.i <> 0 OR z.i <> 0
)
```

The CTE terminates as long there are no more special characters to replace.

The row having the maximum `lvl` value per `id` is the one that contains the stripped down values of `[EpiNum]`, `[Name]`, `[Acct]` fields. Hence you can use the following code to perform the `UPDATE` in a single SQL statement:

```sql
;WITH StripSpecialChars AS (
 ... above query here ...
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[EpiNum] = t2.[EpiNum],
    t1.[Name] = t2.[Name],
    t1.[Acct] = t2.[Acct]   
FROM TableA AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, [EpiNum], [Name], [Acct],
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                      ORDER BY lvl DESC) AS rn 
            From StripSpecialChars) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rn = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d435/1)

**EDIT:**

In case there is no PK column in `TableA`, then you can wrap your table in a `CTE`, simulate a PK using `ROW_NUMBER` and finally perform the update on the `CTE`:

```sql
;WITH TableA_PK AS (
  SELECT [EpiNum], [Name], [Acct],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EpiNum]) AS id
  FROM TableA
), StripSpecialChars AS (
   SELECT id, 0 AS lvl,
          [EpiNum] = REPLACE([EpiNum], SUBSTRING([EpiNum], x.i, 1), ''), 
          [Name] = REPLACE([Name], SUBSTRING([Name], y.i, 1), ''), 
          [Acct] = REPLACE([Acct], SUBSTRING([Acct], z.i, 1), '')          
   FROM TableA_PK
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum])) AS x(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name])) AS y(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct])) AS z(i)
   WHERE x.i <> 0 OR y.i <> 0 OR z.i <> 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT id, lvl = lvl + 1,                       
          [EpiNum] = REPLACE([EpiNum], SUBSTRING([EpiNum], x.i, 1), ''), 
          [Name] = REPLACE([Name], SUBSTRING([Name], y.i, 1), ''), 
          [Acct] = REPLACE([Acct], SUBSTRING([Acct], z.i, 1), '')             
   FROM StripSpecialChars 
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum])) AS x(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name])) AS y(i)
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct])) AS z(i)
   WHERE x.i <> 0 OR y.i <> 0 OR z.i <> 0
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[EpiNum] = t2.[EpiNum],
    t1.[Name] = t2.[Name],
    t1.[Acct] = t2.[Acct]   
FROM TableA_PK AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, [EpiNum], [Name], [Acct],
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id 
                                      ORDER BY lvl DESC) AS rn
            FROM StripSpecialChars) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.rn = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04d2a/1)

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply/time. I think this is my winner as it does not require a function call and looks like it will be fast. One question though, I would like not to have to amend my initial table structure by adding the `id` column. It is not clear to me if this can be done using the above? Any ideas are greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

This might look a bit complicated but I solve a similar challenge with the following:

Just paste this into an empty query window and adapt to your needs...

```
--This function comes back with a running set of numbers - very handsome
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RunningNumbers](@counter INT=1000000, @StartAt INT=0)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
    WITH E1(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)), --10 ^ 1
    E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 10 ^ 2 = 100 rows
    E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 10 ^ 4 = 10,000 rows
    E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 10 ^ 8 = 10,000,000 rows
    CteTally AS
    (
        SELECT TOP(ISNULL(@counter,1000000)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) -1 + ISNULL(@StartAt,0) As Nmbr
        FROM E8
    )
    SELECT * FROM CteTally;
GO

--This function breaks down a string into a one-char-table with one char in each row.
--You can decide for any ascii code what you want to do with this character.
--At the end the whole thing is concatenated again.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetPrintableChars]
(
     @Txt VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Txt=LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@Txt,'')));

    DECLARE @rslt VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @rslt =
        (
            SELECT Repl.ASCII_Code
            FROM dbo.RunningNumbers(LEN(@Txt),1) AS pos
            --ASCII-Codes of all characters in your text
            OUTER APPLY(SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@Txt,pos.Nmbr,1)) AS ASCII_Code) AS OneChar  
            --re-code 
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code IN(9,10,13) THEN CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code) --line and page break
                    WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN 32 AND 126 THEN CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code) --normal printable
                    WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code IN(132,142,148,153,174,175) THEN CHAR(OneChar.ASCII_Code) --extended to keep
                    WHEN OneChar.ASCII_Code BETWEEN 128 AND 154 THEN CHAR(176) --extended to get rid of
                    ELSE ''
                END AS ASCII_Code
            ) AS Repl    
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','varchar(max)');
    RETURN @rslt;
END
GO

--One example to get rid of some characters.
SELECT dbo.GetPrintableChars('This is a Test for special characters: ÐðÑñ')
GO

--And clean up for testing
DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetPrintableChars;
GO
DROP FUNCTION dbo.RunningNumbers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Gordon Linoff makes an excellent point for making the constraint.
If you want to reuse your looping code for multiple fields you can place it in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveSpecialCharacters (
    @String NVARCHAR(max)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i int

    SET @i = patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @String)
    WHILE @i > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String = STUFF(@String, @i, 1, '')
        SET @i = patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @String)
    END
    RETURN @String
END
```

And just reuse the function:

```
UPDATE [TableA] 
SET [EpiNum] = dbo.RemoveSpecialCharacters([EpiNum]), 
    [Name] = dbo.RemoveSpecialCharacters([Name]), 
    [Acct] = dbo.RemoveSpecialCharacters([Acct])
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum]) <> 0 OR 
      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name]) <> 0 OR 
      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct]) <> 0;
```

Do test performance! And if you wish to check the results in c# just use the function in a select and update if it is correct.

Comment: I like this one a lot. However, ideally I don't want to have to create a function and remove it after I am done. Is there a clear way of adapting the query to avoid the function call - I can't see that there is, at least it is not obvious to me?

Comment: @Killercam See Giorgos Betsos answer. It is a little more complex but doesn't require a function (and will perform better). I don't see the problem to leave the function around though, since you might need to reuse it someday.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Create this function:

```
CREATE function f_removebadcharacters
(
  @string varchar(2000)
)
RETURNS varchar(2000)
as
BEGIN
  DECLARE @badcharacters varchar(100) = '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%'

  WHILE @string like @badcharacters
    SET @string = STUFF(@string, patindex(@badcharacters, @string), 1, '')

  RETURN @string
END
```

Call the function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.f_removebadcharacters('Salaries & Wages - Other')
```

In your update, use this syntax:

```
UPDATE [TableA] 
SET [EpiNum] = dbo.f_removebadcharacters([EpiNum])
WHERE [EpiNum] LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%'
```

Here is a working example:

```
DECLARE @TableA table([EpiNum] varchar(2000))
INSERT @TableA 
  values('Salaries & Wages - Other'),
        ('80-82/5 O$%*#@)(J^#oh!@!n & '''' Bacon St')


UPDATE @TableA
SET [EpiNum] = dbo.f_removebadcharacters([EpiNum])
WHERE [EpiNum] LIKE '%[^A-Z0-9 ]%'

SELECT * FROM @TableA
```

Result:

```
EpiNum
Salaries  Wages  Other
80825 OJohn   Bacon St
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time effort, I would suggest running the `update` multiple times until all the characters are gone.  That is probably the fastest way of accomplishing this.

After doing this, fix the table to have a constraint that only accepts the values you want:

```
alter table table1
    add constraint chk_EpiNum_Valie check (EpiNum NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%');
```

(And repeat for each such column.)

Then the database will guarantee the validity of the column on `insert` and `update`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the reply. But how can I do multiple updates and check the results from C# - this is way too messy. There must be a way to get my SQL query to loop. The way the system works is that it is importing raw data from a vast number of different sources and feeder systems so adding constraints is not an option. The need for this comes when users are trying to prepaire their data for our costing system. Anyway,

Comment: @Killercam . . . Of course you can do a loop (as other answers attest to).  My point is:  fix the data in the database.  Add a constraint.  Then you're done.  No C# code at all, the constraint will keep the column clean in the future.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I can't use constraints. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Way to apply your update multiply time and control the result

```
declare @l int;
select @l= COUNT(*) from sys.views  --just to set @@ROWCOUNT to 1

while @@ROWCOUNT >0
begin
  UPDATE [TableA] 
  SET [EpiNum] = REPLACE([EpiNum], SUBSTRING([EpiNum], PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum]), 1), ''), 
    [Name] = REPLACE([Name], SUBSTRING([Name], PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name]), 1), ''), 
    [Acct] = REPLACE([Acct], SUBSTRING([Acct], PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct]), 1), '') 
  WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [EpiNum]) <> 0 OR 
      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Name]) <> 0 OR 
      PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', [Acct]) <> 0;
end
```